# Постоянно отключается, база данных vestaCP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, vesta

поставил на сервер digitalOcean панель управления сервером VstaCp, после чего под ее пользователем установил wordpress, проблема в том, что база данных просто отключается периодически, и ее нужно запускать в ручную, не понимаю с чем это может быть связано так как настройки дефеолтные.

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in
```

после чего:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in
```

и бывает проскакивает ошибка такого рода:

```
PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=15165 in
```

Сайт без нагрузки, после установки стоял ночь и так же база отключилась..
Буду рад вашей помощи

Comment: Изучайте логи БД

Comment: Останавливается сервер БД или теряется коннект?